# apply function is taking forever to exceute

Tags: pandas, database

I have a column which contains bus_types for eg:"Hi-Tech Non A/c","VOLVO-B9R (MULTI AXLE-SEMISLEEPER) A/C" etc . and I have to create another column to say if its is "a/c" or "non a/c".
I tried the following straight forward method of using apply function on the column

```
df['ac'] = df['busType'].apply(lambda x: "non a/c" if "non a/c" in x.lower() else "a/c")
```

The issue is that, since The data set has over 1000000+ rows , The apply function is taking forever to execute . Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: can you post some sample data, maybe `df.sample(n=20).to_dict()`?  This runs fast on my machine (less than half a second for 1m rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which should be faster because not using apply :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'busType':["non A/c  zzzz", "non a/C  zzzz", "a/c  zz", "A/c  zz"]})
df["is_non_ac"] = df["busType"].str.lower().str.contains("non a/c")
df["ac"] = "a/c" 
df.loc[df["is_non_ac"], "ac"] = "non a/c" 
df.pop("is_non_ac")
df
```

[image]

Comment: If it is still too long for you, you can split your csv into multiple csv files and use multiprocessing to process the files. It will make use of all your CPU cores.